# Delete all records from each table having a specific column value

Tags: mysql, database, t-sql, plsql

1. Find every table in the same database that has field Client_ID
2. DELETE only the records where Client_ID = 123

Above is my scenario. I'm wondering if it's possible to do using MySQL with a single query.

Comment: Am I the only one wondering - why this question has a PLSQL tag?

Comment: @MahendarMahi No, I'll add another wondering - why the tsql tag?

Answer (score 0):

You don't know names of tables with Client_ID field, they can be found using the informational schema and stored in a temporary table.
Then, dynamic query should be generated in loop to delete required records. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

No, this can't be done in a single SQL statement.

You'd need a separate `SELECT` statement from the `information_schema.columns` table to identify tables that contain a column with a particular name, e.g.

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE column_name = 'Client_ID'
   AND table_schema = 'mydatabase'
```

You could use the results from that `SELECT` to dynamically generate the required `DELETE` statements. But the names of the tables need to be specified as identifiers in the DELETE statement(s).

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do the job.

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,STRSQL VARCHAR(8000))

INSERT INTO @T(STRSQL)
SELECT DISTINCT 'DELETE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] WHERE CLIENT_ID=123'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'CLIENT_ID'

DECLARE @ID INT, @STRSQL VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @T)>0)
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1
    @ID = ID,
    @STRSQL=STRSQL
FROM @T

EXEC (@STRSQL)
DELETE @T WHERE ID =@ID

END
```